# Was the Mishkan Built on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, midrash, mishkan-tabernacle, vayakhel, tzav

There is a famous midrash that relates the 39 prohibitions of Shabbat to the various types of activities that were required for the mishkan's construction. Implicit within this idea is the notion that the mishkan itself was not erected on Shabbat (so, for example, both Rashi and Ramban on Exodus 35:2, based on the Mekhilta, Parshat Vayaqhel). And yet, there is also a famous midrash to the effect that on each of the seven days prior to erecting the mishkan as a semi-permanent structure, Moses built it in the morning and dismantled it in the evening (see, for example, Seder Olam Rabbah §7). Since it is impossible that there could have been seven consecutive days that did *not* include Shabbat, that would seem to suggest that there was at least one Shabbat on which the mishkan was constructed.

Are these two midrashim at odds with one another? Or is there another way of understanding why the mishkan (which, according to one midrash, cannot be erected on Shabbat) was, according to the other midrash, erected on Shabbat at least once?

Comment: BTW: The Medrash Tanchuma apparently says that it erected twice or thrice daily - even on Shabbat.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question is addressed by several Acharonim.

[R. Pinchas Horowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinchas_Horowitz) says that during the 7 days of inauguration Moshe did not erect the Mishkan by himself. Since multiple people did the act together it was not a violation of Shabbat labor.

**[Panim Yafos Parshas Naso](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39321&st=&pgnum=136)**

> ונראה דהקמת כל שבעה ימים לא היה ע"י משה עצמו כמו כל מלאכת המשכן שנעשה
>   ע"י אחרים ונקרא ע"ש משה משא"כ הקמת השמיני שהיא לקיום נצטוה משה להקימו
>   בעצמו כמפורש בקרא שעשה משה בעצמו ואפשר שהיה אסור לעשות שום מלאכה שלא
>   נצטוה מפי השי"ת לעשות בעצמו כמ"ש חז"ל בר"פ עשרה יוחסין כיון שנתמנה אדם
>   פרנס על הצבור אסור לעשות מלאכה בפני רבים ויש להוכיח זה מדאמר בילקוט
>   בכל שבעת הימים היה מקימו **והיאך מקימו בשבת הא כל מלאכת המשכן לא דחה
>   שבת אלא דהרבה לוים היו מקימין אותו** וקימ"ל דשנים שעשוהו פטורין ואין
>   איסור מן התורה ותו דאין שבות במקדש וי"ל שהיו מקימין ע"י רבים והיינו
>   דיליף רב יוסי מדכתיב סוף פרשת פקודי ויהי בחודש הראשון הוקם המשכן ויקם
>   משה את המשכן משמע להדיא דשני קימות היו הראשון הוקם ע"י הלוים

[R. Yaakov Emden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Emden) says that even though building the Mishkan generally does not override Shabbos, for Moshe during the 7 days of inauguration it did override Shabbos.

[**Siddur Beis Yaakov Ma'amados L'yom HaShabbos**](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42978&st=&pgnum=879)

> ור"ל דה"ט דקדמה בכאן לומר באמת שדוחה את השבת והיינו בהקמת המשכן שהיה
>   מרע"ה מקימו ומפרקו כל ז' ימי המלואים (אע"ג דכה"ג ודאי יש בנין וסתירה
>   באוהל וגם חיוב חטאת יש בו) ומכאן למד לפי שהקדים צווי המשכן לשבת הודיעו
>   שהקמתו דוחה את השבת ולכן הוצרך לסמוך השבת מאחריה ולמעט בשמירתה אך כדי
>   שלא יטעו ישראל לומר ששבת דחויה היא אצל משכן לכל אדם ביום הקמתו לפיכך
>   הוצרך להזהירם לדעת רש"י באך שממעט במשכן מדחיית שבת והיינו לכל ישראל
>   חוץ ממרע"ה

[R. Eliyahu David Rabinowitz Teomim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliyahu_David_Rabinowitz-Teomim) rejects R. Yaakov Emden's explanation and answers simply that the Midrash is lav davka and Moshe erected and disassembled the Mishkan on the other days but not on Shabbos.

**Zechor L'Dovid Mispar Shalem # 9**

> כן נראה לי במה שאמרו בירושלמי פ"ק דיומא ובמדרשים שמשה רבינו ע"ה היה
>   מעמיד ומפרק את המשכן כל שבעת ימי המלואים דלאו דווקא כל שבעה דדל
>   מינייהו יום השבת דאין בנין המשכן דוחה כדא' ביבמות ו' (ב') [א']
>   ובמכילתא ריש פרשת ויקהל ובכמה מקומות אלא הואיל והיו שבעת ימי מלואים
>   נקט בזה לשון הרגיל אף שלא היה מפרק ומעמיד רק ששה מהם

R. Yaakov Zev Yoskovitz suggests that really erecting the mishkan should override Shabbos because it is a prerequisite of the avodah. The reason why it does not override Shabbos is that it is a prerequisite that could have been done before Shabbos. In this case, however, where the specific command was to erect and disassemble the Mishkan on each day it could not have been done before Shabbos, and therefore it overrode Shabbos as a prerequisite to the avodah.

**[Ambuha D'Sifrei Parshas Naso](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34331&st=&pgnum=226)**

> ונ"ל בפשיטות דהנה הא דכל מלאכת המשכן ומקדש אינו דוחה שבת אף דלכאו' הי'
>   ראוי שידחה שבת משום מכשירי עבודה דהא עבודה דוחה שבת אך פשוט משום דהוי
>   מכשירין שאפשר לעשותן מע"ש דקיי"ל דאינו דוחה שבת [ועי' בחי' חת"ס שבת
>   קל"א מש"כ לתרץ הא דקשה לכאו' דלר"א דס"ל דגם מכשירין שאפשר לעשותן מע"ש
>   דוחה שבת א"כ למה לא נאמר דבנין מקדש ומשכן ידחה שבת משום מכשירי עבודה
>   יע"ש דבר יקר] וגם במזבח שנפל בשבת אינו דוחה שבת אף דעתה א"א לעשות
>   מאתמול מ"מ מין מזבח ראוי מאתמול וכמבואר בירושלמי שבת פראד"מ ובירושלמי
>   פסחים פ"ו ה"ג יעי"ש ועי' בעירובין ק"ג גבי נימת כינור שנפסקה ודו"ק ועי'
>   בצל"ח פסחים ר"פ א"ד שנסתפק ביבלת שנולד בשבת אם חשוב א"ר מאתמול ודוחה
>   שבת ודבריו תמוהין מירושלמי הנ"ל וכנודע ואכמ"ל] וא"כ כאן בימי המלואים
>   דהמצוה כן הי' לסתור ולבנות בכל יום מימי המלואים ופשוט דזה הי' מכלל
>   חינוך המשכן וא"כ לא הי' אפשר לעשות מאתמול ושוב הי' דוחה שבת משום
>   מכשירי עבודה שא"א לעשות מאתמול דהרי קרבנו של נשיא לבני אפרים הי' דוחה
>   שבת וע"כ הי' גם הבנין והסתירה דוחה שבת משום מכשירי עבודה וא"ש

Comment: I've thought about R' Pinchas Horowitz's answer before, but I'm not so happy with it.  Yes, there were no derabbanans yet.  But does that mean that throughout the process, construction of the Mishkan continued on Shabbos, just with a shinuy?  It's not impossible, but something about it feels wrong to me.  I would like to think that building the Mishkan didn't happen at all on Shabbos, even for things that aren't melachos deoraisa.  I don't have a proof and I might be wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Six additional answers:

The Chasam Sofer (Toras Moshe, Vayakhel) explains that Moshe did not really construct the Mishkan by himself; it just looked like he was building it but in reality it was constructed by divine intervention (see Rashi on Shmos 40:18).

The Tchebiner Rav (Dovev Meisharim 1:63) writes that since it was only constructed for that day, it does not constitute the forbidden melacha of construction. (This answer is also given by the Chasam Sofer in his teshuvos, OC:72).

The Munkatcher Rebbe (Minchas Elazar 1:65:2) says that it was erected before Shabbos and taken down after Shabbos, and explains the Yerushalmi (Yoma 1:1) accordingly.

The Meshech Chochmah (Bamidbar 7:14) answers that once the Mishkan was inaugurated with shemen ha-mishchah, even its construction was docheh Shabbos.

R. Ben Tzion Chai Uziel (Mishpetei Uziel 3:47:2) explains that at this stage, erecting the Mishkan was considered part of the avodah, which is docheh Shabbos, and was not considered construction of the Mishkan, which is forbidden on Shabbos.

R. Dovid Soloveitchik (Shiurei R. Meshulam Dovid al Ha-Torah, Pekudei) asks on the Chasam Sofer who says that it was built by God--what about deconstructing it, which Moshe did himself? His own answer to the question is that Moshe did this by divine command.

Answer (score 0):

*Building* the Mishkan did not override Shabbos. *Operating* it (*avoda*) did.

Presumably the inaugural sequence was considered *avoda*.

Comment: The inaugural _building_ was an Avoda? Which Avoda is it? I've never heard of such an Avoda.

Comment: We learn out the dinim of binyan from erecting it, so it must have a din of building it (at least according to the stam baavli which only learns from the actual building of the mishkan and not the korbanos)